# Python: "Self" is not not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, self, defined

Back with the same confusing script.. there was A LOT of spacing issues that I fixed... but seem to be missing more?  Whats wrong with this -- its saying line 332 `self` is not defined...

Here are a few lines above and below that script in case it matters:

```
#-Whats being decompiled start
#map(None,*list) = zip(*list)
class areaset(top_tsv):
   def __init__(self, file_name=0, version=0):
       top_tsv.__init__(self, file_name, version)
   self.frombin_map = [    <--- this is 332
   ('ID'        ,{'t':'ulong','lpad':0x04}),
   ('Name'      ,{'t':'str','s':0x48,'rpad':0x1C}),
   ('RGB color'   ,{'t':'color','rpad':0x01}),
   ('Sound effect ID'  ,{'t':'long'}),
   ('Color RGB'   ,{'t':'rcolor','rpad':0x01}),
   ('Lighting RGB value' ,{'t':'rcolor','rpad':0x01}),
   ('Lighting angle'  ,{'t':'float','s':0x03,'f':0x01}),
   ('Is it City?'  ,{'t':'ubyte','rpad':0x03}),
    ]
```

I just cant figure it out, I can't think right now.. there are many other "self is not defined" errors, but if I fix this one, then at least I'll know how to fix the rest. So what do I need to do?

Comment: It would be helpful, both to you and to the people answering your questions, to try and create a more minimal example before pasting it.  If you really can't figure out what's causing the problem, then it's better to paste the whole script than a snippet that won't actually run, but it's better yet to create a small snippet that *does* actually run, and produce the error.

Answer (score 11):

If the code excerpt accurately reflects what's in your program the problem is that you have only a single line in your `__init__` constructor.  You need to fix your indentation.

`Self` is only defined in member functions.  Your non-indented code is not part of the constructor, but is actually getting run when you `import` your class.

One of the great beauties of Python is that it uses indenting to recognize statement blocks rather than curly braces or `begin`, `end`.  You *must* use the indenting correctly for the interpreter to understand your code.

Comment: I'm not convinced "beauty" is the right word. You can't argue the fact, though, that python is a terrific language all things considered. For me, it's well worth putting up with the whitespace issue.

Answer (score 4):

Indentation matters in Python. `self` is defined within the `__init__()`, so assuming you want that `self` to be referred to in line 332, indent it to match the line above.